# Print String multiple times on the same line

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am trying to print a string, multiple times together on the same line.

For example:  User input = 123
and I need to print it 3 times:
123123123

This is my code that i have tried:

```
userString = []

    if val > 0:
    for i in range(val):
        print(userString * val, end = " ")
```

it's giving me a syntax error by the end=""

How can I fix this?

Comment: are you using python 3.X ?

Comment: I am using 2.X @Kasra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using python 2 not python 3 , you can either use:

```
from __future__ import print_function # import the print function
```

Or use:

```
print(userString * val), # <- trailing comma
```

You could also use join and a list comprehension to match the output of your python 3 print code:

```
val = 5
print(" ".join(["*" * val for _ in range(val)])) if val else ""
***** ***** ***** ***** *****
```

Comment: print(userString * val),
this prints 123 X times on the same line and X new lines

Comment: @user2955610, yes either will work but if using the import it must be the very first line in your file

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i have a question, i use mostly python 2x, i know in future 2x will be deprecated, you have any advice for me??. as python 3x is future

Answer (score 2):

```
if val > 0:
   print('%s ' % userString * val)
```